# How to check if an object is a firestore.Timestamp?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a validation function.

Is there a way to check if an object is a `firestore.Timestamp` ?

I'm using the `firebase` JS SDK and also using Typescript.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

const blogPost = {
  title: "",
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()
}

function validateBlogPostCreationDate(blogPost) {
  // SOMETHING LIKE THIS:
  return blogPost.createdAt is a Timestamp ?
    true : false;
}
```

Comment: What sort of code are you writing?  Security rules or something else?  Please expand your code sample and description to be more clear.

Comment: @DougStevenson It's not for security rules. It's an admin form to add/edit blog posts on a website. And `blogPost.createdAt` should be a `Timestamp`. Since I'm exhaustive checking on properties on `blogPost`, I would like to check that as well. When the admin clicks on `Save`, I'll run that validation on client before saving it to Firestore.

Comment: So, what language is this?  Please expand your code to show how the timestamp is created and is supposed to funnel through this code.  And debugging output would be helpful as well.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry for the missing pieces. I've added more details to the question.

Comment: It escapes me why the Firebase clients for JS don't convert Timestamps to native `Date`. They convert `Date` when written to; it would be a no-brainer to do the same when reading.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JavaScript and TypeScript have an [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator that checks the type of an object against a prototype.

```
return blogPost.createdAt instanceof firebase.firestore.Timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who end up here, in the modular API you can do it this way:

```
import {Timestamp} from 'firebase/firestore'
...
if (obj[prop] instanceof Timestamp) {
 // your logic goes here....
}
```